# lwjgl draw element array

Tags: opengl, draw, lwjgl

for about 3h I'm trying to draw simple 3d triangle using glDrawElement function but it seems that I  do something incorrectly here is what I do :

```
float[] verts = new float[9];
 int[] tris = new int[3];
 verts[0]=0;verts[1]=0;verts[2]=0;
 verts[3]=0;verts[4]=1;verts[5]=0;
 verts[6]=1;verts[7]=0;verts[8]=1;
 tris[0]=3;
 tris[1]=2;
 tris[2]=1;

vertBuffer= BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(verts.length);
trisBuffer= BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(tris.length);

vertBuffer.put(verts);
vertBuffer.flip();

trisBuffer.put(tris);
trisBuffer.flip();
```

thats for creating buffers.

```
if(VBOID==-1)VBOID=GL15.glGenBuffers(); 
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOID);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

if(VAOID==-1)VAOID=GL15.glGenBuffers();
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VAOID);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, trisBuffer,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

thats for binding buffers

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOID);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VAOID);

    glPushMatrix();{
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, WIDTH*HEIGHT*2, GL_INT, 0);

    }glPopMatrix();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    Display.update();
```

this is the code for drawing
It works when I draw it directly without passing indexes ,but it does not work this way.
I hope somebody can tell me what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here. First, indices in OpenGL are 0-based. So instead of this:

```
tris[0]=3;
tris[1]=2;
tris[2]=1;
```

you need this:

```
tris[0]=2;
tris[1]=1;
tris[2]=0;
```

Then, `GL_INT` is not a valid index type to pass as the 3rd argument to `glDrawElements()`. The only valid types are `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. While Java does not have unsigned variable types, `int` values can be used where OpenGL expects unsigned values as long as only half of the available range is used (i.e. the most significant bit is 0). So if you stick with `int` indices, you'll need to use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as the argument.

The count (2nd argument) you pass to the draw call also looks very suspicious, even though we don't see the corresponding definitions. The value should be `3` since you're drawing 3 vertices, and `WIDTH*HEIGHT*2` can't be 3, at least as long as `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are integers.

Correcting both of these problems, your draw call should look like this:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

BTW, the `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` calls here are redundant, since you're not applying any transformations.

Comment: Thank you I will try to update with this changes. Really didnt get to the point to change transform :D